# How do I set a different color to "visited" anchors in same page?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set a:visited for anchors on the same page?

http://tinker.io/93e4d/3

What happens now is that whatever style I apply to a:visited goes for all the links before I even click. What I need is maybe something like a:clicked instead of visited, or some way to highlight the last link clicked, but I don't know of anything like that.

Is there anything I can do that does not require js?

thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific pseudo-selector for anchors pointing to the same page. (Not sure how `:visited` works for those, anyway, though?)

Comment: @Pekka 웃: The spec doesn't make that clear, but as it is implemented the current page is considered visited if the user is not in private browsing mode, as it would be immediately recorded in the browser history otherwise. Selectors 4 introduces [`:local-link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#local-pseudo) which will target links with URLs pointing to the same page and any fragments of it.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks! You know your CSS stuff, man.

Answer (score 2):

To set different colours for your links you could go

```
#header a:visited {
}
# nav a:visited {
}
```

Or using a span with a class for each colour

Comment: Hey Chris, off topic, I just saw your deleted question about getting hacked. SO is unfortunately not a good source for live help with such issues. This canonical resource may provide useful first steps: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/q/218005) If you use a off-the-shelf solution like Wordpress, Google `<name of application> hacked` for first aid. If it's a big thing, it may be worth getting professional help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> What happens now is that whatever style I apply to a:visited goes for
>   all the links before I even click.

May be all your links have same `href`

These should work

```
a {
   color: red;
}

a:visited {
   color: blue;
}

a:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: each link points to a different element, but they're all in the same page, so i think the browser considers them all "visited", even if the  links haven't been clicked yet. You can see it here: http://tinker.io/93e4d/3

Comment: Clear browser cache and history and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Set a different class for each anchor.

```
a.first:visited {}
a.other:visited {}
```